# Categorizing people of North African descent (i.e. Egypt) on Ethnicity surveys/questions for US documents?

Tags: united-states, ethnicity, egypt

I'm half Egyptian (the other half is a mixture) but born and raised in the USA; I've always read conflicting sources of whether to categorize myself as "White" or "African American" on those surveys that you usually have to fill out for anything official. My father tells me to list myself as "White" but logic tells me to list myself as "African-American" since geographically Egypt *is* technically in Africa; I feel like I'm being somewhat dishonest if I only choose one of those options, and usually only one ethnicity or "Other" is optional.

Some unclear sources I've looked at:

- [Ancient Egyptian race controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_race_controversy)
- [Would Egyptian be considered African American](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/college-admissions/306701-would-egyptian-be-considered-african-african.html)

Comment: To me it seems incredibly anachronistic that an official form in any country would still be using a term like "White" to try and encapsulate a person's race/ethnicity.

Comment: This is not a genealogy question -- I suspect it may be one of those questions that doesn't belong on any stackexchange site, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't entirely sure if this would be the best site; I was thinking of the History or Politics sites as well, but I am still satisfied with the Answer I received here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [US Census Bureau](http://www.census.gov/prod/cen2010/briefs/c2010br-02.pdf) defines "White" as:

> A person having origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the
>   Middle East, or **North Africa**. It includes people who indicated their
>   race(s) as "White" or reported entries such as Irish, German, Italian,
>   Lebanese, Arab, Moroccan, or Caucasian.

We could have an endless debate on whether this is a reasonable racial subdivision, but by this definition you are likely considered by the US government to be White. It is impossible to say whether or not this is an accurate representation of your ancestry.

DNA testing of your autosomal DNA may provide insight into your deep ancestry, however any ethnicity results must be treated with caution.

You may identify with a different ethnicity than your race, nevertheless race and ethnicity are frequently conflated.